# Why are structure pointers (methods) in C considerably slower than normal functions?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have been using C in more and more projects recently and almost ended up creating my own "object implementation" with structure pointers. However, I was curious on the speed difference between a purely functional style (with structs) and structures that call on function pointers in a more modern day object orientated style.

---

I have created a sample program and am unsure why the difference in timing is so large.

The program uses two timers and records the time taken to complete each task (one after the other). This does not include memory allocation/de-allocation, and both techniques are setup in a similar way (each structure has three integers as pointers of the struct).

The code itself just adds three numbers together repeatedly in a for loop for the duration specified in the macro **LOOP_LEN**.

Please note I have the functions being measured both **inlined** and the compiler optimisation was varied from none to **Full Optimization (/Ox)** (I am running this in Visual Studio as a pure .c file).

---

## Object style Code

```
// MAGIC object 
typedef struct {

    // Properties
    int* x;
    int* y;
    int* z;

    // Methods
    void(*init)(struct magic* self, int x, int y, int z);
    int(*sum)(struct magic* self);

}magic;

// Variable init function
void* init(magic* self, int x, int y, int z) {

    // Assign variables to properties
    *self->x = x;
    *self->y = y;
    *self->z = y;

    return;

}

// Add all variables together
inline int sum(magic* self) {
    return ((*self->x) + (*self->y) + (*self->z));
}

// Magic object constructor
magic* new_m(int x, int y, int z) {

    // Allocate self
    magic* self = malloc(sizeof(magic));

    // Allocate member pointers
    self->x = malloc(sizeof(int));
    self->y = malloc(sizeof(int));
    self->z = malloc(sizeof(int));

    // Allocate method pointers
    self->init = init;
    self->sum = sum;

    // Return instance
    return self;
}

// Destructor
void delete_m(magic* self) {

    // Deallocate memory from constructor
    free(self->x); self->x = NULL;
    free(self->y); self->y = NULL;
    free(self->z); self->z = NULL;
    free(self); self = NULL;

    return;

}
```

---

## Functional (traditional) style code

```
// None object oriented approach
typedef struct {
    int* x;
    int* y;
    int* z;
}str_magic;

// Magic struct constructor
str_magic* new_m_str(int x, int y, int z) {

    // Allocate self
    str_magic* self = malloc(sizeof(str_magic));

    // Allocate member pointers
    self->x = malloc(sizeof(int));
    self->y = malloc(sizeof(int));
    self->z = malloc(sizeof(int));

    // Return instance
    return self;
}

// Destructor
void delete_m_str(str_magic* self) {

    // Deallocate memory from constructor
    free(self->x); self->x = NULL;
    free(self->y); self->y = NULL;
    free(self->z); self->z = NULL;
    free(self); self = NULL;

    return;

}

// Sum using normal structure type
inline int sum_str(str_magic* self) {
    return ((*self->x) + (*self->y) + (*self->z));
}
```

---

## Timer test and main program entry point

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define LOOP_LEN 1000000000

// Main entry point
int main(void) {

    // Start timer for first task
    clock_t start1, end1, start2, end2;
    double cpu_time_used1, cpu_time_used2;

    // Init instances before timer
    magic* object1 = new_m(1, 2, 3);

    // Start task1 clock
    start1 = clock();

    for (int i = 0; i < LOOP_LEN; i++) {
        // Perform method sum and store result
        int result1 = object1->sum(object1);
    }

    // Stop task1 clock
    end1 = clock();

    // Remove from memory
    delete_m(object1);

    // Calculate task1 execution time
    cpu_time_used1 = ((double)(end1 - start1)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    // Init instances before timer
    str_magic* object2 = new_m_str(1, 2, 3);

    // Start task2 clock
    start2 = clock();

    for (int i = 0; i < LOOP_LEN; i++) {
        // Perform function and store result
        int result2 = sum_str(object2);
    }

    // Stop task2 clock
    end2 = clock();

    // Remove from memory
    delete_m_str(object2);

    // Calculate task 2 execution time
    cpu_time_used2 = ((double)(end2 - start2)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    // Print time results
    printf("----------------------\n    Task 1 : %.*e\n----------------------\n    Task 2 : %.*e\n----------------------\n", cpu_time_used1, cpu_time_used2);

    if (cpu_time_used1 < cpu_time_used2) {
        printf("Object Oriented Approach was faster by %.*e\n", cpu_time_used2-cpu_time_used1);
    }
    else {
        printf("Functional Oriented Approach was faster by %.*e\n", cpu_time_used1 - cpu_time_used2);
    }

    // Wait for keyboard interrupt
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

---

Every single time the program is ran, the functional programming always performed faster. The only reason I could think is that it has to access an extra layer of pointer through the structure to call the method, but I would have thought inline would reduce this delay.

Although the delay gets smaller as the optimization is increased, I would be curious to know why it is so much different at levels of low/no optimization and is this therefore considered a valid programming style?

Comment: What do you mean by "both inlined"? MSVC is not able to inline your OO code. At the same time it is able to defeat your benchmark by generating none code at all for 2nd case.

Comment: Could you try compiling it with optimizer off, and see if you get similar differences in performance?

Comment: `self = NULL;` is superfluous and possibly a bug, if the programmer now think that the freed item points at NULL. It does not.

Comment: Not sure whether it's relevant, but this looks very much like comparing virtual and non-virtual method invocation in a language like C++.  You might find related material by searching on "virtual method" and "performance".

Comment: Anyway, your code has no side effects so I expect both loops to yield one big fat `NOP` for both cases. Voting to close as cannot be reproduced, since this benchmarking doesn't make sense. Now what you need to do is for examples to copy the results into allocated arrays, then go print or volatile access some random spots of these arrays outside the benchmarking.

Comment: @Lundin - ... or one tiny thin NOP.  `;-)`

Comment: I've found that, if the code includes a DNS query, both take about the same time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your 2nd loop with `/O2` loop is compiled into:

```
    call     clock
    mov      edi, eax ; this is used later to calculate time
    call     clock
```

E.g. there is *no code at all*. Compiler is able to understand that result of `sum_str` function is unused, so it removes it completely. Compiler is not able to do the same for the first case.

So there is no real comparison when optimization is enabled.

Without optimizations there are just more code to execute.

First loop is compiled to:

```
    cmp      DWORD PTR i$1[rsp], 1000000000
    jge      SHORT $LN3@main                 ; loop exit
    mov      rcx, QWORD PTR object1$[rsp]
    mov      rax, QWORD PTR object1$[rsp]    ; extra instruction
    call     QWORD PTR [rax+32]              ; indirect call
    mov      DWORD PTR result1$3[rsp], eax
    jmp      SHORT $LN2@main                 ; jump to the next iteration
```

Second loop:

```
    cmp      DWORD PTR i$2[rsp], 1000000000
    jge      SHORT $LN6@main                 ; loop exit
    mov      rcx, QWORD PTR object2$[rsp]
    call     sum_str
    mov      DWORD PTR result2$4[rsp], eax
    jmp      SHORT $LN5@main                 ; jump to the next iteration
```

With both `sum` and `sum_str` being compiled to equivalent sequences of instructions.

The difference is in one instruction in loop, plus indirect calls are slower. Overall there shouldn't be a huge difference between two versions without optimizations - both should be slow.

Answer (score 1):

I think Ivan and you have already provided the answer. I just want to add about inline function. Even though you declare a function as inline it not necessary that compiler will always consider it as inline. Based on complexity compiler might consider it as normal function.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the former case has additional indirection of pointer reference. Though you declare `sum` as a inline function, as `sum` function pointer is put into object member, it cannot be inlined easily.

I suggest you compare generated assembly code with `-O0` ~ `-O3`.